# How to clear json api response from windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am developig a windows app 8.1. Where I am calling an json api in a page say "Page1". My issue is that when I navigate to another page say "Page2" and come back to "Page1", I recive the same data from the api. I found that when I come back to the Page1 again, my web api is called but the result is come from I guess from cache.So, json data is not updated. How can I overcome with this issue. Any suggestion is most welcome.

My Rest API Call Code Is

```
var client = new HttpClient(); // Add: using System.Net.Http;
var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
response.Dispose();
client.Dispose();
return ressult.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the calling url just add a random parameters like

```
string uri = string.format(http://www.myservice.com?time={0}",DateTime.Now);
var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(uri));
```

Comment: thanks, its work fine. But can I clear the cache, and will it work than instead of sending a random paramenter.

Comment: @DhurbaJyotiBaishya if you have control over the cache mechanism then it's fine, the method I provided is used mainly when consuming other's API